# How can I set a maximum order amount for a particular customer?

Tags: orders, customer, extensions

I'm looking for an extension or customization that allows me to cap a particular customer from ordering over a given amount. For example, a customer cannot checkout if their Order Total is beyond $500.

Answer (score 2):

Magento have revered logic for `minimum order amount for order place`.

magento have managed from `validateMinimumAmount function at class of` `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` of object of `sales address object`.

If you have add `here some logic then it would be fill` you require.

so,Rewrite class of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address using below signtex:

```
<sales>
    <rewrite>
        <quote_address>MymoduleNameSpace_Mymodelname_Model_Sales_Quote_Address</quote_address>
    </rewrite>
</sales>
```

rewrite class is MymoduleNameSpace_Mymodelname_Model_Sales_Quote_Address

```
<?php
class MymoduleNameSpace_Mymodelname_Model_Sales_Quote_Address extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address
{
    public function validateMinimumAmount()
    {

    $parentCheck=true;
    /* call default magento  validateMinimumAmount class */
    $parentCheck=parent::validateMinimumAmount();
    /*   i have put static amount */
    $amount=100000;
    if($parentCheck==true){
    /* check here you total cart  base subtotal amont is less then your $amout then you canot checkout */ 
        if ($this->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() < $amount) {
        return false;
        }
    }
    return $parentCheck;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can this be used to set a maximum order amount by customer? Or is it for all customers?

Comment: It is for all customers.

Comment: Yes,Fabian.I got mistake. I will update it today.Thanks for your feedbackup

Answer (score 1):

Amit has a good start. To have it only for one customer, you need to get the amount from a customer, so here is the way:

1. `create a new customer attribute`
2. `use this instead of a hard coded amount:`

   ```
   $amount=$this->getOrder()->getCustomer()->getMaxAmount();
   ```

should work for a new attribute `max_amount`